# Jasmine mock promise resolve not being handled when called in controller construtor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In my controller constructor, a lot of the private variables are set as the result of a promise returned from a service.

For example, this will be called when the controller is being constructed.

```
MyService
    .initializeDataForType(type)
    .then(function (data) {
        //never getting hit when testing
    });
```

And the service call is mocked to return a resolved promise like so.

```
var myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('page.MyService', [
    'initializeDataForType'
]);

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$q_) {
    myService.initializeDataForType.and.callFake(function (type) {
        var deferred = _$q_.defer();
        deferred.resolve({});
        return deferred.promise;
    });

    target = $controller('page.MyController', {
        'page.MyService': myService 
    });
}));
```

The `then()` method for the service call is never being reached.  It seems that jasmine isn't waiting and moving on to the next test.

Comment: the `'page.MyService': MyService` should have the `myService`-spyObject right? Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, typo.  I'll correct it.

Comment: Just a speculation: Could it be because the promise has been resolved before the `then`-function is registered? Maybe if you create the `deferred` in the outer scope and resolve it after the `$controller()`-call

Comment: The defer only gets resolved when the service is called in the constructor.  It should only exist in the scope of the anonymous function.

Comment: but i'll try it anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `$scope.$digest()` after instantiating the controller? In jasmine tests, you have to force scope digest cycles and since you variables are set as a result of a promise, a digest cycle needs to be run before testing to see whether those variables exist.

Comment: No I haven't.  Thanks.  I'll give that a try

Comment: I ended up going with `$rootScope.$apply()`, but both solutions worked.